# Прямое дополнение в родительном падеже

Tags: грамматика, дополнение

В учебной литературе одно и то же: прямое дополнение может быть в родительном падеже при переходном глаголе с отрицанием и в конструкциях вроде "выпить воды" или "купить  яблок", где родительный падеж - это так называемый родительный частичного охвата.

А как быть тут:

1. "Ищу место в зале". Переходный глагол в сочетании с  винительным падежом без предлога - прямым дополнением.
2. "Ищу места в жизни". Тот же глагол, то же самое слово (пусть и с некоторым метафорическим значением), однако оно в родительном падеже.

Это что - уже косвенное дополнение? Отрицания нет, частичного охвата тоже.

Или вот:

"Ждать (что?) поезд".

"Ждать (чего?) поезда".

Тут как быть? Дополнения идентичны по значению - разве что второе, возможно, как-то менее конкретно. Оно косвенное или прямое?

Короче, родительные при переходных с отрицанием и родительные "части вещества" (например, "налей вина") есть прямые дополнения.

А вот родительный отвлеченного значения при переходном глаголе ("дай мне смелости!") или даже конкретный родительный при переходном глаголе, но не имеющий значения "части вещества" ("ждать поезда"), - это косвенные дополнения или допустимо считать их прямыми?

"Лев добыл смелость" и "Лев добыл смелости", - может, и тут "смелости" - это частичный охват?

Answer (score 2):

Понятие **прямого дополнения** связано с понятием **о переходных глаголах,** действие которых распространяется на объект, выраженный прямым дополнением в форме В.п.

**В Грамматике 80** назван именно В.п.: действие охватывает объект целиком, а не только его часть (**выпить воду –  выпить воды**); предмет мыслится конкретно, а не абстрактно: **ждать поезд –  ждать поезда**).  Значение переходности утрачивается при отрицании: **пил воду –  не пил воды**.

В настоящее время **сущ. в Р.п. при переходных глаголах могут считаться прямыми дополнениями,** хотя правильнее было бы сказать, что они **занимают позицию** прямого дополнения.

Ищу (конкретное) место в зале. –  Ищу места (абстрактное понятие) в жизни.

Жду (конкретный) поезд из Москвы. –  Жду поезда (в метро).

Лев добыл смелость (стал смелым). –  Лев добыл смелости (стал смелее).

Comment: Похоже, "настоящее время" зарапортовалось: а как с его точки зрения надобно называть дополнение в родительном падеже при замене глагола на непереходный ("добыл" на "набрался")? Оно перестанет быть "прямым" при _точно таких же_ грамматических связях? Под циркулярное определение переходности глагола по винительному падежу подстроится? Или под это уже новое определение переходности подогнано?

Comment: Проблема с Р.п. при переходном глаголе довольно противоречивая. Переходный глагол не может существовать без прямого дополнения, оно для него обязательно. И если уж нет дополнения в В.п., то ему приходится довольствоваться дополнением в Р.п., которое замещает В.п., занимает его позицию. Смысл замены в том, что Р.п. может выразить дополнительные оттенки значений.

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

Переходность глагола определяется строго по винительному падежу - прямому дополнению.

Если в позицию винительного падежа поставить родительный падеж этого же слова и если в целом, кроме небольших оттенков значения, ничего не меняется, то и такой родительный есть смысл понимать как прямое дополнение - и глагол в таком случае сохраняет переходность.

Иначе говоря, винительный падеж - "обязательное требование" при определении переходности глагола.

Винительный падеж - прямое дополнение, а родительный в этой позиции как бы "факультативен", и его можно считать прямым дополнением, только если есть "обязательный" винительный, а он, родительный, как бы "замещает" винительный.

Ждать (что?) поезд - "обязательный" вариант.

Ждать (чего?) поезда- "факультативный" вариант с "замещением" винительного родительным.

Как тогда быть с "набрать грибов"? Нельзя сказать "набрать грибы". "Грибы" при "набрать" будут только в родительном, и родительный не встает в позицию винительного (которого тут не может быть). Выходит, в "набрать грибов" формально возможен только родительный падеж дополнения ("обязательного" винительного нет), а раз так, то дополнение будет косвенным, а раз оно косвенное, то и глагол будет, кхм, непереходным (в этом значении и в сочетании именно с этим словом).